# restructure json missing elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

Original json data:

```
{
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

Expected json data:

```
{ 
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations":    [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"         
         "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Male",          
                  "Name": ABCD
                }
            ],
              "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]

      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"          
        "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": EFGH
                },
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": IJKL        
                }
              ],
        "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""

}
```

Program:

```
//Original JSON data in question.
var Implementations = {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}

// Program that make the conversion
var finalResult = [];
for (var i=0; i<Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
  var currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];
  var targetObj = {
    "Male": {
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    },
    "Female": {
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    }
  };
  for (var j=0; j<currentImplementation.Country.length; j++) {
    var currentCountry = currentImplementation.Country[j];
    if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Male') {
      targetObj.Male.Country.push(currentCountry);
    } else if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Female') {
      targetObj.Female.Country.push(currentCountry);
    }
  }
  finalResult.push(targetObj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult));
```

How do I add the objects like Personality Traits, Eating Habits, Reading Habits, Fitness Habits and attributes like Universal and common outside of the Implementations object in the current program?

Comment: It is a basic thing adding properties to JavaScript objects. What have you tried so far?

Comment: for (var k=0; j<currentImplementation.PersonalityTraits; j++) {
    var currentPersonalityTraits = currentImplementation.PersonalityTraits[k];
    if (currentPersonalityTraits.Type === 'Positive') {
      targetObj.PersonalityTraits.push(currentPersonalityTraits);
    } else if (currentPersonalityTraits.Type === 'Negative') {
       targetObj.PersonalityTraits.push(currentPersonalityTraits);
    }
  } This is what I have tried so far but it does not show up in the response.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your question correctly, I think your code already gives you the expected JSON for Implementations property.

```
[
  {
    "Male": {
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",
          "Name": "ABCD"
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Female": {
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "EFGH"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "IJKL"
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Therefore, if you are asking how to add the rest of the properties to achieve your expected JSON, you could just do this:

```
Implementations.Implementations = finalResult;
```

that will replace the original JSON implementations property to the one you have created.

Therefore say:

```
var Implementations = {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

if you do Implementations.Implementations = filteredResult; 
the Implementations  will become:

```
{
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
  {
    "Male": {
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",
          "Name": "ABCD"
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Female": {
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "EFGH"
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": "IJKL"
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

Otherwise, explain a bit more of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The program only addresses Implementation Property. If you scroll down in my expected response how do I add the Personality Traits, Reading habits, Eating habits, Fitness Habits after the Implementations?To keep it short, I want the exact response as-is from the expected json response in question by tweaking the current program. Currently, I don't see  anything after the Personality Traits down to the bottowm when I run the program.

Comment: is originalJSON a module? I am getting not defined error.

Comment: Could you please add the snippet in the comment? I quite didn’t get how do I implement your response. Do I add the whole Json in another variable?

Comment: @Eva I will make a smaller object since I cannot copy and paste your JSON object. var x = {UniversalOne: "", CommonOne: "", Implementations: []}; if you do x.Implementations = filteredResult; it will still have UniversalOne, CommonOne as per the original x, but x.Implementations will be replaced with filteredResult. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Got it, now it makes sense-thanks a lot! After trying the above I run into the error at for (var i=0; i<Implementations.Implementations.length; i++)  length not defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer. My last two lines of code are:                                                  
  finalResult.push(targetObj);  
  Implementations.Implementations= console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult));                    
 I don't see the expected json response. I have to push the targetObj otherwise it gives me empty array. If I dont added JSON.stringify it gives empty objects without any data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196841/discussion-between-eva-and-glen-k).

Comment: That worked like magic!! Thank you for being patient and helpful.